# implementing a function to count coins

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programming and this entire thing confuses me. My prof has given us an assignment that he hasnt taught us how to do nor is it in our text book. please help! The question is "Given the number of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies, implement a function to get the total amount of money you have on hand"

this is using python 3

thanks!

Comment: It's unclear of what you're asking us to do. If it's to do your assignment for you, [that's not what were for](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). We aren't a homework dump-n-do service. Please attempt to do it, show your attempts, then ask questions about problems you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be doing you a disservice by writing the code for you but this should help you get started in the right direction. I'd actually recommend reading [this article](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gmelvin/polya.pdf) first though.

As described in the article, the steps to solve a problem are:

1. Understand the problem - what are you being asked to find or show? Do you understand all of the terms/words used? Do you have enough information to solve the problem? Do you have enough "background knowledge" to be able to solve the problem?

   This step sounds like it should be obvious but a lot of people skip it. For example, a lot of people who ask questions on this site will ask something like "how do I write *x* in C#?" and only admit later after some probing that they don't actually know C#. Well, in that case, they're obviously missing critical background knowledge, so the first step for them is to go read some tutorials on C#.

   In this case, the terms include "Python," "Python 3," "function," as well as currency terms like "quarters," "dimes," "nickels," etc. I'm assuming you know what quarters, dimes, etc. are (although I guess that might be confusing depending on where you're from; for example, I read an article awhile back that referred to a "kopek" and I had to look it up to know that that's 1/100th of a Ruble).

   The questions, then: Do you know Python well? If not, you probably want to read a tutorial on it (or review your lecture notes and/or textbook if they gave information on Python). Do you know how Python 3 differs from, say, Python 2.7? (Hint: there are major differences). Are you familiar with what a Python function is and how they are written?

   Some of that's probably obvious, but you'd be surprised by how many people skip one of those steps. I've done it before myself actually - start working on a problem only to realize that I didn't really understand it fully or that I didn't know what one of the terms meant. Creativity consultant Todd Henry attributes a failure to understand the problem fully as one of the major causes of "stuckness" across *all* creative fields (not just software engineering or mathematics).
2. Devise a plan
3. Execute the plan
4. Look back/reflect - test your solution, think about if there are better ways to do it, etc.

First for understanding the problem. Forget about programming for a second - if I handed you a bunch of change and asked you to count it "by hand," how would you do it? ("How would *you* do it" is actually remarkably helpful in many cases). For example, if I gave you 5 quarters, 3 dimes, 2 nickels, and 3 pennies, how much money is that? Think about different ways you could do that:

- 5 quarters = 0.25 * 5 = $1.25
- 3 dimes = 3 * 0.10 = 0.30.
- 2 nickles = 2 * 0.05 = 0.10.
- 3 pennies =  3 * 0.01 = 0.03.
  Thus, the answer is $1.25 + $0.30 + $0.10 + $0.03. What you're being asked to show or do is to write a program that will do something like what I just did "automatically."

Hopefully, that clears up the "understanding the problem" part. At this point, I'll leave steps 2 - 4 up to you.

Here are a few scenarios you might want to test:

- One or several of every kind of coin
- Several of one kind of coin, none of any of the rest (e.g. 5 quarters and nothing else or 3 dimes and nothing else)
- Some of several of the 1 quarter, 3 dimes
- Cases where the amount of a coin equals or exceeds a dollar - e.g. 120 pennies, 10 dimes, 4 quarters, etc.
  Try to test different "kinds" of scenarios as well as "edge cases." Bugs are *much* more likely on the "edges" of valid inputs. If the professor says that you can't have more than $1 of any coins, for example, test it with 0, 1, 99, 100, and 101 pennies. 99 and 100 should "work" normally and it should "reject" or "fail gracefully" with 101 pennies.

Comment: sounds good to me EJ

Answer (score 0):

The core data is two arrays, one is the array of coin amounts, the other is the array of coin values. You need to loop through the arrays, multiply the value from one array by the other, and add up the total.

You can do this manually using a loop (which is good practice as you can then implement this in any language) or use the python "sum" function, for arrays a and b, over the length of the arrays.

sum( [a[i] * b[i] for i in range(len(b))] )